How to call up the current value of a pgfkey
I created a pgfkey with the systematic
\ifthefilled % filled 3/3
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=lightgray}}% filled=true
\else
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none}}% filled=false (default)
\fi

In the drawing of the tikzpicture it works fine; but if I say 
\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}

I alway get the default value ("false"); what do I have to do to get the current value?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifthefilled% filled 1/3
%
\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,
% filled 2/3 ==================
filled/.is if=thefilled,
filled/.initial=false,% Default
% ===========================
}

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={align=left, font=\footnotesize}]
\tikzset{MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1}%
%
\def\pkv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/##1}}%
%
\ifthefilled % filled 3/3
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=lightgray}}% filled=true
\else
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none}}% filled=false (default)
\fi

\draw[cyan, thick, FillStyle] circle [radius=5mm] 
   node[below=7mm, black, draw]{    
 filled: \pkv{filled}};% Problem here
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%% end of cmd %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\MyCmd~~
\MyCmd[filled=false]~~
\MyCmd[filled]
\end{document}

€dit: Seems there was a bad fragment, but now it should run.

@cfr Oh... maybe now?

From a quick glance: You're overloading the key. The .is if installs a code that does \csname thefilled#1\endcsname after checking that #1 is either true or false. But the parser does not check if a key holds a value if it founds it to be a code key. You might want to do filled/.append code=\pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}{#1} . Though, this will lead to inconsistency if you provide neither true nor false. Maybe a custom .is if handler is better suited which gives a nice interface. (\ifthefilled true\else false\fi would give you the proper “value”.)

@Qrrbrbirlbel Uh, phew. Do I understand correctly that the method with the \newif is unfavorable (apart from the incorrect "word output")?
I would be interested to know how to do this better or purely with pgfkeys. Could you summarize this into an MWE?

So, yes, you use the correct interface to “call up” the value of your value-key but your key isn't a value key anymore – in a way. The \newif and the .is if handler go hand in hand and is IMO the correct approach if you really need a toggle. You could also just do filled/.is choice, filled/true/.style={FilledStyle/.style={fill=lightgray}}, filled/false/.style={FilledStyle/.style={fill=none}}, filled/.default=true to have the same interface, then you don't need to check any \ifs anymore. It comes down to why you think you need the \ifthefilled macro or \pkv{filled}.

@Qrrbrbirlbel Ok, that seems more elegant...

A PGFKeys key is either a code key or a value key which is initialited with the .initial key (which sets up the initial value), everything else is a code key. (Internally stored with a /.@cmd suffix.)
When you or your user uses a key, i.e. filled = true or just filled, the PGFKeys parser has to figure out what the key actually does and how it works. This process is rather simple: It checks first if it's a code key and if it is, it executes it with the given value (might be the default value specified by .default – which .is if sets up to be true – or a special no-value marker). And that's it.
Only if it's not a code key, PGFKeys checks if it's a value key and if there is an explicit value given it sets the value-key to it (otherwise it just return the value of the key).

Why do you need \ifthefilled?
You don't really need it if you just want to set FillStyle:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  filled/.is choice,
  filled/.append code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}{#1},
  filled/true/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={fill=lightgray}},
  filled/false/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={fill=none}},
  filled/.default=true, % filled ≙ filled = true
  filled=false} % initialize FillStyle and value

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={align=left, font=\footnotesize}, MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1]
  \draw[cyan, thick, FillStyle] circle [radius=5mm]
    node[below=7mm, black, draw]{filled: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\MyCmd~~\MyCmd[filled=false]~~\MyCmd[filled]
\end{document}

You could go a step further and provide your user with an interface to change how the two different styles would look like (maybe one wants another color, maybe one wants a pattern instead of filled area):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  FillStyle/yes/.style={fill=lightgray},
  FillStyle/no/.style={fill=none},
  filled/.is choice,
  filled/.append code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}{#1},
  filled/true/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={MyCmdSettings/FillStyle/yes}},
  filled/false/.style={/tikz/FillStyle/.style={MyCmdSettings/FillStyle/no}},
  filled/.default=true, % filled ≙ filled = true
  filled=false} % initialize FillStyle and value

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodes={align=left, font=\footnotesize},
    MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1]
  \draw[cyan, thick, FillStyle] circle [radius=5mm]
    node[below=7mm, black, draw]
      {filled: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\MyCmd~~
\MyCmd[filled=false]~~
\MyCmd[filled, FillStyle/yes/.style={fill=red}]
\end{document}

Of course, the latter can also be solved with a TeX-if by using FillStyle/\ifthefilled yes\else no\fi:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newif\ifthefilled
\tikzset{
  MyCmdSettings/.cd,
  FillStyle/yes/.style={fill=lightgray},
  FillStyle/no/.style={fill=none},
  filled/.is if=thefilled,
  filled/.append code=\pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}{#1},
  filled/.initial=false} % initialize value

\newcommand{\MyCmd}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    nodes={align=left, font=\footnotesize},
    MyCmdSettings/.cd,#1]
  \draw[cyan, thick, MyCmdSettings/FillStyle/\ifthefilled yes\else no\fi] circle [radius=5mm]
    node[below=7mm, black, draw]
      {filled: \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}


All solutions use an .append code handler on the key filled to have it also set it value-key part. That way, the given value is stored away and can retrieved if necessary.
If you need this often, we can create handlers that include this for both .is if and .is choice.

OK, I understand. I found the "\ifthefilled" in the manual. I think it can sometimes have advantages (but not hiere), e.g. \ifthecycled--cycle \fi - ya, I'll think about it when the time is right... Thx.

But: I remeber the reason was I need at a other position \ifthefilled --cycle\fi. I think that was the reason for that  \newif\ifthefilled. Here at the circles that makes less sense.

@DavidCarlisle told me, I can use the key like
\UseName{if\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/SpiroSettings/filled}}\node[draw]{its filled};\fi
too. So - very good.  Thx again. `

@cis Yes, \UseName is just the L3 interface to, in this example, \csname if\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/MyCmdSettings/filled}\endcsname. This would obviously break if you do filled=foo but that will raise a PGFKeys error first so should be clear enough.
